# python sort list by substr

Tags: python, list, sorting, lambda

I would like to sort a list by a substr of the contents.
Imaginbe the following list and I would like it to be sorted by the number after the '-':

```
>>> lst = ['ABC-789','DEF-123','GHI-456']
>>> sorted(lst,key=lambda x=lst.split('-') x[1])
```

This gives me:

```
    sorted(lst, key=lambda x=lst.split('-');x[1])
                ^
SyntaxError: expression cannot contain assignment, perhaps you meant "=="?
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Is it always a 3-digit code at the end? You could also just slice: `lambda s: int(s[-3:])`

Comment: BTW, your syntax error is coming from the `lambda x=`. For anonymous functions, the syntax is `lambda variable_s: expression`, using a colon `:`, *not* the assignment operator `=`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
sorted(lst, key=lambda x: int(x.split('-')[1]))
```

Output:

```
['DEF-123', 'GHI-456', 'ABC-789']
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider this corrected version:

```py
lst = ['ABC-789','DEF-123','GHI-456']
lst = sorted(lst,key=lambda x: int(x.split('-')[1]))
print(lst)  # ['DEF-123', 'GHI-456', 'ABC-789']
```

You had two issues here.  First, your lambda syntax was off, and you want `lambda x: <expr in x>`.  Second, since you want to sort numerically, after extracting the string to the right of the hyphen, you also should be casting to integer.  Coincidentally, you can get away with this now, because all numbers are the same text width (3 digits).  But, should the numbers not all be the same width, sorting by text might not give a numerical sort.

Comment: Oof.. I posted this first.. but no worries, have an upvote for the detailed explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = ['ABC-789','DEF-123','GHI-456']
lst.sort(key=lambda x:x.split('-')[1])
print(lst)
```

Corrected the lambda and split syntax. Also, I have used the list.sort method instead of sorted in case the original list needs to be sorted and changed.

Comment: "use `list.sort`" ...why? Maybe OP doesn't want to modify the original list. You should explain why you think it's necessary to use the in-place sorting method versus returning a new list from `sorted`.

Comment: `list.sort` in case the original list needs to be modified.